# How to reduce streaming latency Pulseaudio output using Rygel?

Tags: pulseaudio, dlna, rygel

I followed this procedure to stream my Pulseaudio output into a dlna device (A Samsung TV) with  [Rygel](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Rygel/Pulseaudio).

It's working, but, I have a latency around 40 seconds.

I'm on Ubuntu 14.10. Here, is my `~/.config/rygel.conf`:

```
[GstLaunch]
enabled=true
launch-items=myaudioflac;myaudiompeg;myaudioraw

myaudioflac-title=FLAC audio on @HOSTNAME@
myaudioflac-mime=audio/flac
myaudioflac-launch=pulsesrc device=upnp.monitor throttle-time=100 ! flacenc
```

Is there a solution to have a correct latency (Around 1 or 4 sec.)?

Answer (score 0):

Rygel appears to use a 64K sized buffer that cannot be configured. ([source](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/rygel-list/2013-February/msg00014.html)) This means that even with no compression there is likely 1.5 seconds (stereo) to 3.0 seconds (mono) delay simply filling those buffers. Likely much more delay if using compression techniques that reduce the size of audio samples drastically, eg. you can likely fit 5+ seconds of audio into a 64K buffer.

You can try disabling compression as a workaround.

One can also modify the [64K buffer size in source](https://github.com/GNOME/rygel/blob/ecac663d958967f0f320b57da3ecf08920456bc9/src/media-engines/gstreamer/rygel-gst-utils.vala#L84) and recompile.